# Rails: How to put font-awesome symbol in will-paginate label?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, font-awesome, will-paginate, slim-lang

I am using [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) and [font-awesome-rails](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) gems in my app.

I want to replace will_paginate 'Previous' and 'Next' labels with [this](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/angle-left/) font-awesome symbol.

To replace those will_paginate labels I can write this piece of code (I am using [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/)):

```
= will_paginate @articles, :previous_label => 'my_own_text', :next_label => 'my_own_text'
```

but I don't know how to insert any font-awesome symbol there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`will_paginate` exposes only few things to be able to customize the look and feel of the pagination, which covers most of the cases, but not all the cases.

Try this:

```
= will_paginate @articles, :previous_label => '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>', :next_label => '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
```

I haven't tested it. If it doesn't work, then the only way I can think of is to monkey-patch the `will_paginate` pagination renderer.

Comment: That actually works! It doesn't work when you put it beetwen quotation marks but it does when u put it between apostrophes (And that is only thing I didn't try).